# Gnu sort: stray characters in field specification

Tags: linux, shell, gnu, gnu-coreutils

`sort` doesn't seem to like my key specification. Why?

```
~/tmp $ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Packaged by Cygwin (8.25-1)
~/tmp $ echo 'a;b;c;d;e;f;g'|sort --field-separator=';' --key=1,5,2                                          
sort: stray character in field spec: invalid field specification '1,5,2'
```

From the man page:

*-k, --key=KEYDEF : sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type*

*KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a field
number and C a character position in the field; both are origin  1,  and  the  stop
position defaults to the line's end.*

Since the .C and OPTS part in the KEYDEF is optional, a key specification F,F,F (i.e. just the field numbers) should be correct. What did I do wrong?

BTW, my environment is Cygwin, running the Z-shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two fields in -k arg are the START AND END fields.  You can specify -k ANY NUMBER OF TIMES, to sort on multiple keys.  So, -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 will sort first on field 1, then field 2 then field 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it finally!

Comment: Or, more simply, `-k1 -k2 -k3`

Comment: Note that, according to [the help](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html), "the stop position defaults to the line's end", so, e.g., `-k1,1 -k9,9` can behave differently than `-k1 -k9`. (I.e., with `-k1`, `-k9` will effectively be ignored when there is a difference in fields 2 to 8.)

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I should have taken the man page more literally. The definition for KEYDEF says

```
F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]
```

and not

```
F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]...]
```

which means that only 1 or 2 fields can be supplied, not an arbitrary number. This explains the error.

As a side note, I believe there *is* still an error in the man page. The KEYDEF definition says that *the stop position defaults to the **line's** end*. This can't be true, can it? IMO it should be *the stop position defaults to the **field's** end*.

UPDATE: My explanation is NOT correct. See the answer provided by @tedtoal for a correct explanation.

Comment: I believe the man page is correct about the line end - I stumbled across a case where a key `-k9` was ignored when used with a preceding `-k1` if there was a difference in the fields in between. Using `-k1,1` then made the sort work as expected.